# Comparacion de fechas con condicionales JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Quisiera comparación de fecha cuando llegue el día se muestre un console log que diga genial y si no es la fecha no salga otro mensaje y si cambio la fecha que no es la actual salga "BUU".

```js
var fecha = Date();
var diadelevento = new Date("Sep 08, 2020");

if (fecha.getTime == diadelevento) {
  console.log("Genial");
} else {
  console.log("BUUU");
}

console.log(diadelevento);
```

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? Y qué error te da?

Comment: debes entender que la expresión **fecha.getTime == diadelevento** siempre va a ser falsa dado que **fecha.getTime** retorna un número y **diadelevento** es un objeto Date.

Comment: la cuestión es que no me compara por ejemplo la fecha por ejemplo quiero que ejecute genial cuando se la fecha exacta que digo en la Var diadelevento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo el mensaje solo debe mostrarse si las fechas son iguales, la hora se vuelve irrelevante, entonces puedes utilizar los métodos de `Date()`, para obtener dia, mes y año, luego hacer la comparación sin importar la hora, algo asi:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var diadelevento = new Date("Sep 08, 2020");

if (fecha.getDate() == diadelevento.getDate() && fecha.getMonth() == diadelevento.getMonth() && fecha.getFullYear() == diadelevento.getFullYear()) {
  console.log("Genial");
} else {
  console.log("BUUU");
}

console.log(fecha.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(diadelevento.toLocaleDateString());
```

Tambien podrias hacerlo así, simplemente convirtiendo las fechas a cadenas para luego comparar si son iguales:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var diadelevento = new Date("Sep 08, 2020");

if (fecha.toLocaleDateString() == diadelevento.toLocaleDateString()) {
  console.log("Genial");
} else {
  console.log("BUUU");
}

console.log(fecha.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(diadelevento.toLocaleDateString());
```

Seguramente haya mejores formas de hacerlo, pero por ahora esas son las que se me ocurren. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda es que soy nuevo JS aveces me confundo y quiero aprender

Answer (score 0):

Debes primero setear el tiempo en 0 ya que la fecha introducida no cuenta con un tiempo que por defecto es 00:00:00, una vez igualado el tiempo ya podrías comparar las fechas.

```js
var fecha = new Date((new Date()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
var diadelevento = new Date("Sep 08, 2020");

if (fecha.getTime() == diadelevento.getTime()) {
  console.log("Coincide");
} else {
  console.log("no coincide :()");
}

console.log(fecha.getTime(), diadelevento.getTime());
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda es que soy nuevo JS aveces me confundo y quiero aprender